# OpenGL Unbind texture

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have a huge list of 2D Textures that I load each time a map loads (Depending on the map and it's contents). I'm looking for a way to anyhow unbind a bound texture to reduce usage of memory. The bind texture function works perfect just don't see any function to unbind some ids or all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &texID)
```

This should remove texture from memory. Before that call be sure to unbind currect texture by simply calling:

```
glBindTexture(target, 0) // << default texture object
```

[glDeleteTextures spec](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml)

Comment: So by ``<< default texture object`` you mean put my texture id instead of ``0``? Another thing is I'm using C#, not C++ but it has these functions.

Comment: `0` means that OGL will unbind your texture ID. This is done in order not to delete active texture (texture that is being used when drawing for instance). Please pass `0` there, not your textureID.

Comment: The OpenGL specification says that deleting texture objects implicitly unbinds them. What it does not do, however, is remove them from attachment points to FBOs. GL will immediately make the texture ID free for re-use and unbind it when you delete the object, but since FBOs may still reference the original texture object the memory that the texture used will not be freed until all references are removed.

Comment: @111WARLOCK111: don't confuse "unbind" with "release the memory". Only ONE texture is bound at a time - think of it as the currently active texture. Binding one texture unbinds any previous texture - it is a single global variable. If one is bound when a draw.. call is performed, then it is used. The point of binding 0 is to make sure no texture is active, on any future draw. "delete" is what releases the memory.

Comment: So the texture id goes in the location of `target` and the 0 would be the second argument for the unbind operation, or did you mean something else?  Because I see that the argument names in the BindTexture function are 'target,texture'...

Comment: Also, you are saying to run that operation *before* calling delete *with* the texture ID (which you would have just unbound)...which would now be unbound -- this is confusing. Do you really mean what you have said up there, or perhaps you meant something else...?