# OpenGl ES 1.0 Android Unbind texture to free memory

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am currently working myself through the book "Beginning Android 4 Games Development" by Mario Zechner ( Developer of libGDX).

I stumbled over a certain code snippet describing on how to free memory in the gpu when unbinding and deleting textures in OpenGL ES 1.0:

[image]

Then some pages later he builds a Texture class which should handle the overall work:

```
    public class Texture {

GLGraphics glGraphics;
FileIO fileIO;
String fileName;
int textureId;
int minFilter;
int magFilter;

public Texture(GLGame glGame, String fileName) {
    this.glGraphics = glGame.getGLGraphics();
    this.fileIO = glGame.getFileIO();
    this.fileName = fileName;
    load();
}
private void load() {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL(); int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
    textureId = textureIds[0];
    InputStream in = null; try {
        in = fileIO.readAsset(fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        setFilters(GL10.GL_NEAREST, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load texture '" + fileName +"'", e);
    } finally {
        if(in != null)
            try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

public void reload() { 
    load();
    bind();
    setFilters(minFilter, magFilter); glGraphics.getGL().glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
public void setFilters(int minFilter, int magFilter) {
    this.minFilter = minFilter;
    this.magFilter = magFilter;
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter); gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
}
public void bind() {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
}
public void dispose() {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    int[] textureIds = { textureId };
    gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
}
}
```

What really confuses me is that he uses:

gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, **textureId**);

in the dispose() method:

```
     public void dispose() {
      GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
      int[] textureIds = { textureId };
      gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
     }
```

As far as stated above it should be 0 instead of textureId,
to make sure the current texture to be deleted is not bound, and overwritten with the default by using 0.
Isn't he doing just the opposite like this, when he passes textureID?
As far as I understood this will definitely make it the current bound texture. So it might be deleted but is still referenced??

I tested the code with both versions, changed the textureId with 0,
and it is always the same output, it doesn't draw the texture anymore, which is good, BUT is the texture deleted in video RAM?
Even if I comment out the whole line it works. But I am confused what
would be correct to make sure the texture is also freed in video RAM.

In this topic:
[OpenGL Unbind texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986990/opengl-unbind-texture)
the last answers speak about the difference and some FBO. What is this?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: does this also apply for OpenGl Es 1.0 ?
what ist this about then:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986990/opengl-unbind-texture

"The OpenGL specification says that deleting texture objects implicitly unbinds them. What it does not do, however, is remove them from attachment points to FBOs. GL will immediately make the texture ID free for re-use and unbind it when you delete the object, but since FBOs may still reference the original texture object the memory that the texture used will not be freed until all references are removed."

Comment: So you think I can delete the "gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);" line? I guess I am not using a FBO either.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :) It totally confused me :D I also appreciate the Manual Pages link. Wasn't sure earlier if its the right documentation to look into ;)